# Can not retrieve all selected values from list of Comboboxes mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a list box control that has a text block and a combobox for a list item. This is dynamically generated from an ObservableDictionary but once I have selected my item I can not retrieved the selected values. I can see them in the live visual tree it I click on each individual Combobox but I am unable to use them. I need to retrieve a dictionary containing ShoplistItem  for the key and the SelectedValue from the availability combobox. Below is some code

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" />
                <StackPanel>
                    <ComboBox 
                        x:Name="dictCombobox" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Value}" 
                        IsEnabled="{Binding IsSelected, 
                            Mode=TwoWay, 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"
                        SelectedValuePath="Key" 
                        SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedAvailability, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    </ComboBox>
             </StackPanel>
         </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

c#

```
public class ShopAndAvailabilityDataContext : Shop, IPersistent
{
    public Shop _Shop;
    public Availability _ups =new Availability();
    public ObservableDictionary<Shop, Availability> availabilityDict{ get; set;
}

public ShopAndAvailabilityDataContext ()
{
    _Shop= new Shop();
    availabilityDict= _ups.Availabitity;
}
```

And I have been using the datacontext to get all the other properties and the code below for the selected value. This only shows me the 1st item in the list with the shop @Index 0 and the 1st item in the availability array. How can I achieve this and what am I doing wrong based on my approach. Any and all ideas are welcome

```
private KeyValuePair<Shop, Available> selectedAvailability;
public KeyValuePair<Shop, Available>SelectedAvailability
{
    get 
    {
        return selectedAvailability; 
    }
    set
    {
        selectedAvailability = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("Availability");
    }
}
```

Comment: What does Available and Availability look like?

Comment: @Philip w 

public enum Available
        {
            NotAvailable = 0,
            LimitedAvailability  = 1,
            Avialable= 2
        }

Availability
Array Availability= Enum.GetValues(typeof(Available));